# How to find out the clock pin number of an FPGA?

Tags: fpga, simulink, xdc

I'm using FPGA-in-Loop function in MATLAB/Simulink and it requires the clock pin number, if I want to choose a board without off-the-shelf support packages. How should I find out the specific pin number of an FPGA?

I know there are documents, such as master XDC for Xilinx. But how to get the data for other FPGAs e.g., Altera boards? I don't find them in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways: look on the board schematic, look in the constraints files of example projects for the board.

The schematic is probably easier. You'll have to look for clock sources for the FPGA. If there's only one on-board oscillator module that goes to the FPGA, that's straightforward enough. Otherwise it might be one clock from multiple clock sources, and/or from off-board pins for some module boards.

In a Xilinx constraints file (normally .xdc), you'd be looking for the clock name amongst the pin definition constraints.

To see a Xilinx Vivado project's constraints files, open the project, got to the Project Manager then select Hierarchy on the Sources window. That will list the project's constraints files, if they exist.